# Modifying Bootstrap variables when using bootstrap-sass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, sass

Here are all the less bootstrap variables: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html

I've used the bootstrap-sass gem to add twitter bootstrap to my rails app which means I'm using sass. How do I modify/edit these less variables in my bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss file?

When I try to do something like this:

```
@navbarBackground: #3D368B;
```

I get:

> Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home
>
> Showing
>   /Users/justme/myproject/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
>   where line #5 raised:
>
> Invalid CSS after "@navbarBackground:": expected pseudoclass or
>   pseudoelement, was " #3D368B;"

Answer (score 9):

Variables in Sass start with a dollar sign ($) not an at symbol (@) which is used in Less.

Try this:

```
$navbarBackground: #3D368B;
@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

Answer (score 4):

to modify variables in saas, modify them before importing bootstrap

```
.alert{
  margin-top:-40px;
}



@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap-responsive";
```

here in an example in my app